# Smallest trace of a matrix product where one is given and the other is orthogonal

Tags: matrices, optimization, non-convex-optimization, stiefel-manifolds

What are the optimal solution and optimal value for the following semidefinite program

$$ \min_{ V } \{ \mbox{tr} (V\Sigma) : VV^T=I \}$$

where $\Sigma$ is a given positive semidefinite matrix, and both $V$ and $\Sigma$ are squared matrix?

Also, what are the optimal solution and optimal value for the following semidefinite program

$$ \min_{ V } \{ \sum_i v_i^T\Sigma v_i: VV^T=I \}$$

where $\Sigma$ is a given positive semidefinite matrix, both $V$ and $\Sigma$ are squared matrix, and $v_i$ is the $i$-th column of $V$?

Comment: What is $\Lambda$ ? Are $V,\Sigma$ square real matrices ? Since $V$ is not symmetric, what do you mean by $V>0$ ? All this is not serious...

Comment: @loupblanc Thx. Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to a  change of orthonormal basis, we may assume that $\Sigma=diag(\lambda_i)$ where $\lambda_i>0$.

If $V=[v_{i,j}]$, then

$tr(V\Sigma)=\sum_i v_{i,i}\lambda_i\geq -\sum_i \lambda_i=tr((-I)\Sigma)$.

Conclusion. The $\min$ is reached for $V=-I$ and its value is $-tr(\Sigma)$.

Comment: Thanks! A related question, what if we minimize instead $\sum_i v_i^T\Sigma v_i$, where $v_i$ is the $i$-th column of $V$?

Comment: $\sum_{i} v_{i}^{T}\Sigma v_{i}=\sum_{i} \mbox{tr}(\Sigma v_{i}v_{i}^{T})=\mbox{tr}(\Sigma V)$ by the cyclic property of the trace.

Comment: @BrianBorchers If so, then how could the optimal value be negative?

Comment: There's a mistake in my comment in that $\sum_{i} v_{i} v_{i}^{T}$ is $VV^{T}$, and by the constraint $VV^{T}=I$, so this would be $\mbox{tr}(\Sigma)$.